# How to find count of mismatches in two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: RDat1 and RDat2. I am trying to find counts of occurrence in which the publisher_id in R1 did not match what was in publisher_id in R2 over the time range of 2015-01 to 2015-06. I join the two tables based on a shared key in queue_id. Here is the query that I have written but it would always return 0...

```
Select count(*)
from RDat1 r1
join RDat2 r2 on r2.queue_id = r1.queue_id
where r1.publisher_id <> r2.publisher_id and r1.lead_time between 
'2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-06-30 23:59:59' 
;
```

Comment: Which table denotes alias l?

Comment: Please revise your question, in SQL the provided query would return "The multi-part identifier "l.lead_time" could not be bound" because there is not a table with alias l in your query.

Comment: It's R1. Revised. Apologies.

Comment: Can rows be in either table without a match in the other? Can `publisher_id` be null?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `*` and `JOIN`. If the tables are big enough,  it will interrupt with timeout message.

Comment: Does the query return count greater than zero if you remove the time range clause?

Answer (score 0):

Use a left outer join rather than a inner join. This will bring back all data in r1 and null I'm r2. You can then at least see all data and if anymatch. You can then filter down further if need be

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(publisher_id) from RDat1 r1 where r1.publisher_id not in (select publisher_id from RDat2 r2 where r2.queue_id = r1.queue_id) and r1.lead_time between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-06-30 23:59:59' ;
```